# Haskell basic function definition problem

Tags: function, haskell, definition

I'm learning Haskell and I'm trying to write a function to return a list of factors for a number. Here's what I have:

```
factors :: Int -> [Int]
factors n = [x | x <- [2..s], n `mod` x == 0]
    where s = floor (sqrt n)
```

When I try to load the module in `ghci`, I get two errors,

```
p003.hs:3:14:
    No instance for (RealFrac Int)
      arising from a use of `floor' at p003.hs:3:14-27
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Int)
    In the expression: floor (sqrt n)
    In the definition of `s': s = floor (sqrt n)
    In the definition of `factors':
        factors n = [x | x <- [2 .. s], n `mod` x == 0]
                  where
                      s = floor (sqrt n)

p003.hs:3:21:
    No instance for (Floating Int)
      arising from a use of `sqrt' at p003.hs:3:21-26
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Int)
    In the first argument of `floor', namely `(sqrt n)'
    In the expression: floor (sqrt n)
    In the definition of `s': s = floor (sqrt n)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parameter has type `Int`, so you cannot calculate a square root for it.  You need to convert it to a floating point type first, which you can do with fromIntegral.  Unlike some other languages, Haskell does not automatically promote integers to floating point numbers (nor do any other automatic type conversions).

So change `sqrt n` to `sqrt (fromIntegral n)`.

Answer (score 9):

### The cause of the problem

The type of the `sqrt` function is

```
sqrt :: (Floating a) => a -> a
```

You can check this by typing `:t sqrt` in ghci.

`Int` is not an instance of `Floating`, which is why you're seeing the second error.

The cause of the first error is the same; checking `:t floor` reveals that the type is:

```
floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

The function is expecting an instance of `RealFrac`, and you're supplying an `Int`.

Typing `:info RealFrac` or `:info Floating` reveals that neither has an instance for `Int`, which is why the body of the error says

> No instance for ... Int

---

### The solution

The solution to this problem, is to make sure that the types are correct; they must be members of the proper type classes.

A simple way to do this is to use the `fromIntegral` function, which `:t` reveals is of type:

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

Using `fromIntegral` is necessary because the incoming type is `Int`, but the functions `floor` and `sqrt` operate on types `RealFrac` and `Floating`, respectively.

It's allowed because, as you can see from the type signature, `fromIntegral` returns an instance of `Num`, which includes both the `RealFrac` and `Floating` types.  You can convince yourself of this by typing `:info Num` and `:info Float` into ghci, and viewing the output.

Making his change to your program would have the final result below, which should work as you want:

```
factors :: Int -> [Int]
factors n = [x | x <- [2..s], n `mod` x == 0] 
    where s = floor (sqrt $ fromIntegral n)
```

---

### Further reading

Two good resources for understanding exactly what's going on are the Haskell tutorial's sections on [Type Classes](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html) and [Numbers](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html).

Comment: I think you might want (`div` 2) instead of sqrt.